# Is it possible to calculate covariate-adjusted correlations for a specific value?

Tags: correlation, covariance

I would like to control for the influence of IQ on the inter-correlations between a range of cognitive tests.  However rather than doing so at a group level using partial correlation, I would like the strength of correlations to be adjusted according to a given IQ value.

My ultimate goal is to explore whether IQ-adjusted inter-correlations influence the number of abnormally low scores estimated using a Monte Carlo simulation. Is it possible to adjust correlations in this way? I am new to R, so any help on the code would be helpful too. Thank you!